# expand my excel table (+formulars) automatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I created a excel table that perform a mathematical [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). 
It works! But my current table assumes that the equation has three unknown variables(x,y,z).

For example when I got a equation with 2 or 4 unknown variables, I have to edit my table manually. 
How can I realize it that my table adjusts automatically when I give the table the information about the count of variables.

Answer (score 0):

write a vba macro to do what you do yourself when you `edit my table manually`

Answer (score 0):

if the task is to solve a system of N linear equations, you can prepare your matrix for the maximum N you would encounter and fill your parameters from the top left, as "unused" variables (set to 0) will not influence the result. You can make use of the [MDETERM(array)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/mdeterm-HP005209172.aspx) function and apply it to  [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) .